# jQuery with PHP&MySQL autocomplete cannot work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Study jQuery from online tutorial, find many tutorials, just find one simple maybe good for newbie. 
Here is the code for index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
    Autocompletement    
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="suggest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="suggest" placeholder="Type a Country Name..." onkeyup="suggestion()"/>
<div id="autosuggest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for suggest.php:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

function auto($data){
    global $mysqli;
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $query = "SELECT code, name_en 
              FROM countries 
              WHERE name_en LIKE '%$data%' 
              OR code LIKE '%$data%'";

    $items = '<ul class="suggestion">';

    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
         /* fetch associative array */
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             $items .= '<li>'.$row['name_en'] . ' ' . $row['code'].'</li>';
         }
         $items .= '</ul>';
    }else{
        $items = "No results Found..."; 
    }

    echo $items;
} 

auto();

?>
```

Here is the code for suggest.js

```
function suggestion(){
    var suggestVal = $('#suggest').val();

    if(suggestVal != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'suggest.php?data='+suggestVal,
            success: function(data){
                $('#autosuggest').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The result above will only show "No results Found...", it seems that processing file suggest.php is not working, then I test it with a test file test.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host","user","pass","database");
//auto();

$data = $_GET['input'];
//$data = "ca";
 $query2 = "SELECT code, name_en FROM countries WHERE name_en LIKE '%$data%' OR code LIKE '%$data%'";

echo "<br>" .$query2;
echo "<br>";
if($mysqli){
    echo "Yes SQL";echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "No SQL";echo "<br>";
}
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT code, name_en FROM countries WHERE name_en LIKE '%$data%' OR code LIKE '%$data%'");

if($result->num_rows){
    echo "Yes Result";echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "No Result";echo "<br>";
}
```

The weird thing is that I cannot find anything wrong with my code, checked php.net sample and seems all to be good? But when I check `vam_dump($result)` then it is "`null`", any helps will appreciated. 
Here is the test.php output:

```
SELECT code, name_en FROM countries WHERE name_en LIKE '%ch%' OR code LIKE '%ch%'
Yes SQL
No Result
```

URL: http://IP/project/jquery/auto_diy/test.php?input=ch

Comment: Seems your input doesn't have the `id="suggest"`. Give this a whirl `<input type="text" name="suggest" id="suggest"` that ought to work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for reminding it, have added id to the index, but still no success

Comment: You're welcome. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`. Also check your console and for JS console errors if any.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you again, have tried your suggestion, weird thing is that I cannot fetch any objects from database, if possible, can you help me check test.php code on the topic, anything wrong with fetching objects? Error"Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /project/jquery/auto_diy/suggest.php on line 16" that is $mysqli->query

Answer (score 0):

You defined your function as having a `$data` argument

```
function auto($data){...}
```

but you are calling it without the argument,

```
auto();
```

this will trigger a notice.

The argument is not needed, since you are already using `$data=$_GET['data'];` inside your function.

Then in your `ajax` call you should change it like so

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'suggest.php',
    type: 'get', // this can be omitted because GET is default
    data: 'data='+suggestVal, // or
    // data: {data:suggestVal}
    success: function(data){
        $('#autosuggest').html(data);
    }
})
```

---

Update:

in `test.php` output directly the value of $result->num_rows

```
print "Rows returned: " . $result->num_rows . "<br>";
```

if you get zero rows, copy the query and run it in phpmyadmin or a mysql console to verify the data.

in `suggest.php`, update this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (!$result) {
    print 'Could not execute query';
}
else {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $items .= '<li>'.$row['name_en'] . ' ' . $row['code'].'</li>';
    }
}

$items .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you, already reversed on my code, but it seems to be the same result. Can you help me take a look at that test.php code, if test.php could work, I think then I can figure out which part is wrong.